# Javascript / Flash notifications in Slideshow Pro

Tags: javascript, xml, flash, actionscript, slideshow

I am using SlideShow Pro (a flash slideshow/media player) on a site. I want to receive notifications (in JavaScript) from the flash player when a video is finished playing so I can load another video via Ajax. There is an onVideoEnd() ActionScript call in the API:

http://wiki.slideshowpro.net/SSPfl/API-onVideoEnd

In ActionScript:

```
listenerObject = new Object();
listenerObject.onVideoEnd = function():Void {
    // Insert your code here.
}
slideShowProInstance.addEventListener("onVideoEnd", listenerObject);
```

How do I receive notifications or execute this in JavaScript? Slideshow Pro comes with many examples of how to send messages TO SlideShow Pro, but none on how to receive notifications via JavaScript. The docs say that the entire API is available via JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you're embedding their code in your own SWF? If so then set up ActionScript based listener for this event and from your listener, call out to JavaScript with ExternalInterface.call() method.